# Performing named cell additions in EXCEL VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a cell that is named `DATA_FIELD_NAME` and I would like to use it in the following way:

```
Private Sub LockCells(iNumberOfDataColumns As Long)
  ActiveSheet.Unprotect
  ActiveSheet.Cells.Locked = False
  ActiveSheet.Range("DATA_FIELD_NAME:DATA_FIELD_NAME+iNumberOfDataColumns").Locked = True
  ActiveSheet.Protect Contents:=True
End Sub
```

Essentially I would like to lock the range of cells starting from the `DATA_FIELD_NAME` cell horizontally to `DATA_FIELD_NAME + n`.

However this doesn't work. Could someone please tell me the correct syntax or an alternate method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd try this:

`ActiveSheet.Range("DATA_FIELD_NAME").Resize(1, iNumberOfDataColumns).Locked = True`

Here is a [reference on Range.Resize](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/HV080553487.aspx) Basically it changes the amount of cells you are dealing with based upon the current range. In what I gave you, it changes to 1 row, and iNumberOfDataColumns columns.

Comment: This worked perfectly..would you please explain why it works and how `Resize` works? Thanks!

Comment: Added a reference and a brief explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I just wrote this in SO, not tested in XL, so it might contain typos, but this should work:

```
With ActiveSheet
   Range(.Range("DATA_FIELD_NAME"), .Range("DATA_FIELD_NAME").Offset(0,iNumberOfDataColumns)
End With
```

The idea is to combine `Offset(rows, cols)` with to use the `Range(range1, range2)` syntax.
Alternatively, you could be a dynamic range name as explained [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/830287).